# How to write SQL statement for this case?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables as below:

- `tbl_campaign_name`
- `tbl_backer`
- `payment_cellcard`

I want to select all the campaign name from `tbl_campaign_name`, but with the combination of `tbl_backer` and `payment_cellcard`.

How should the combination look like?

Well, there are fields as amount in `tbl_backer`, but it has a status field also, which i consider 1 as approved, 0 as unapproved. `payment_cellcard` has no status, which means it is always approved.

**The problem:**

I want to select the campaign name from `tbl_campaign_name` to list them down in one list, with the amount of money that have been approved from `tbl_backer` and sum with payment_cellcard which is always approved.

below is my query, which it sum up the amount even the status from tbl_backer is not approved yet.

```
SELECT
    tbl_campaign_name.camp_id                      AS camp_id,
    tbl_campaign_name.is_featured                  AS is_featured,

    SUM(ifnull(payment_cellcard.payment_cellcard_amount, 0)) 
                                                   AS cellcard,
    SUM( ifnull(tbl_backer.total_amount, 0)) 
                                                   AS backed_amount,
    (SUM( ifnull(payment_cellcard.payment_cellcard_amount, 0)) +
            SUM( ifnull(tbl_backer.total_amount, 0))) 
                                                   AS total_donation
FROM ((tbl_campaign_name
LEFT JOIN tbl_backer
    ON ((tbl_campaign_name.camp_id = tbl_backer.camp_id)))
LEFT JOIN payment_cellcard
    ON ((tbl_campaign_name.camp_id = payment_cellcard.camp_id)))
WHERE (tbl_campaign_name.is_featured = 1)
GROUP BY tbl_campaign_name.camp_id
ORDER BY (SUM( ifnull(payment_cellcard.payment_cellcard_amount, 0)) + SUM(ifnull(tos_backer.total_amount, 0))) DESC, 
        tbl_campaign_name.camp_id
```

The result:
I got all the project listed as I want, but it sum up even the

```
tbl_backer.backer_status = 0
```

I hope this is clear explanation of what I want.

Thanks,

Comment: WHERE (tbl_campaign_name.is_featured = 1) GROUP BY tbl_campaign_name.camp_id  in this sentence why you don't want to use AND tbl_backer.backer_status = 1 ?

Comment: please provide sql fiddle,

Comment: @SahinYanlık i did try that, and it is only listed the project that have amount is approved, and the rest were gone

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab0b85/1/0

Comment: Thanks @Duke for the fiddle it would be great if you add data in your fiddle so that i can make query thats appropriate